# Secured Hive Streaming Kerberos Exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, kerberos

I am using secured hive streaming , in a cluster with Kerberos Authentication.

I use hadoop : 2.7.3.2.6.1.0-129
 and hive : 1.2.1000.2.6.1.0-129

I am able to get the Ugi authenticated with my kerberos id and keytab at

```java
ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("user@XX.QQQ.NET", "/home/xx/user.keytab");
```

but later when the fetchTransactionBatch is called, Kerberos IO failure occurs at

```java
TransactionBatch txnBatch = secureConn.fetchTransactionBatch(numTrx, writer);
```

code snippet:

```java
HiveEndPoint hiveEP = new HiveEndPoint(hiveConf.getVar(ConfVars.METASTOREURIS), database, table, partArray);
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.conf", "//etc//krb5.conf");
UserGroupInformation ugi;
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("user@XX.qqq.NET", "/home/xx/user.keytab");
if (ugi==null)
{
    return;
}
UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(ugi);
StreamingConnection secureConn = hiveEP.newConnection(true, hiveConf, ugi);
int numTrx = 2;
String[] fieldNames = {"number", "name"};
boolean ifc = ugi.hasKerberosCredentials();
DelimitedInputWriter writer = new DelimitedInputWriter(fieldNames,",", hiveEP);
TransactionBatch txnBatch = secureConn.fetchTransactionBatch(numTrx, writer);
```

Exception at : TransactionBatch txnBatch = secureConn.fetchTransactionBatch(numTrx, writer);

> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1884)
>   at
>   org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.fetchTransactionBatch(HiveEndPoint.java:424)
>   at ns.KClass.(KClass.java:112) at ns.KClass.main(KClass.java:45)
>   Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.StreamingIOFailure:
>   Failed creating RecordUpdaterS for
>   hdfs://MAIN/hdfs/path/to/database.db/acid1 txnIds[113,114] at
>   org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.AbstractRecordWriter.newBatch(AbstractRecordWriter.java:193)
>
> **> caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot
>   authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is:
>   "lh.net/1.2.3.4"; destination host is: "yyy.net":8020;**

Can someone tell me how to solve this exception and get the Transaction batch.

Thanks.